# Opinion based question

Tags: discussion, opinion-based

This question is entirely about opinion and cannot have any one definite answer.  Why has it not been closed?

[Subjects to discuss while on break with older colleagues](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/80517/subjects-to-discuss-while-on-break-with-older-colleagues)

Comment: "Why has it not been closed?" - because not enough people have voted to close it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To answer your question plainly: because it hasn't gotten enough votes to be closed as such. Mods don't really sort through questions looking to close them; that's the community's job as a whole.

Comment: This is clearly the correct answer to the question as asked. I don't know why it was downvoted.

Answer (score 1):

It *is* answerable in the general case where a strategy is given rather than specific examples of topics.  The advice given in the highest upvoted, accepted answer doesn't try to tell the OP what to say, merely that they should just simply talk about what interests them.

Answers that try to give the OP a list of topics are unhelpful and, as you say, entirely opinion based.  However, there is a reasonable recommended *strategy* that the accepted answer addresses.

Comment: What is a general case?  Can you expand on that term and it's meaning in this context?  Can you point to a meta post or something that expands on that? I asked a question on workplace some time ago, which was clearly about the definition of a term. I told a story to expand on the history behind why I was asking.  My question was closed as opinion based.  This question also contains a story and a lot of random commentary on personality traits.

Comment: @mrsuttonsaiditfirst As in the answer, the general case is when you give a strategy (in this case, talk about what interests you), as opposed to the specific case where you give examples of what to talk about.

Comment: @mrsuttonsaiditfirst I have edited the answer.

Comment: I expanded on my comments.  It seems to me that Workplace moderation policies are based upon whims and not any knowable criteria.

Comment: This apparent attempt at a policy is not being followed: http://meta.workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/2693/custom-off-topic-close-reasons-change/2696#2696

Comment: Members of the community use their own discretion with regards to upvoting, downvoting or closing questions.  Sometimes I agree with the outcome, sometimes I don't.  But it's the _community_ that decides how to treat a particular question.  I have no doubt there are inconsistencies, but that's how a community-based moderation system works.

Comment: And that is why I don't post here anymore.  The "community" is ultimately a hierarchy of bullies who enjoy marking questions as "closed" or "off-topic" or "Real questions have answers."  My question did have an answer and I was coming to the community to validate my intuitions about it.  Good people are avoiding it for that very reason. Moderators should be able to police blatantly off-topic content, but nothing else.

Comment: You always have the option of coming to meta with your question and explaining why it should be reopened.  A decent proportion of closed questions do get reopened, they sometimes only need minor adjustment to go from what the community deems unanswerable to answerable.  I suggest if you feel strongly that your question warrants reopening, that you post here in meta.

Comment: "Moderators should be able to police blatantly off-topic content, but nothing else"  Just to clarify, moderators don't close questions, users with the abilty to vote to close do.  Only on very rare occasions to the mods unilaterally close questions.

Comment: I appreciate your responses.  I will consider getting my question reviewed here for re-opening.  I was aware that users can vote to close.